# Finding a specific package's name via the terminal

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg, software-uninstall

Under the 'Installed' tab in the Ubuntu Software app there are some programs which I don't need such as 'AisleRiot Solitare' or 'Mines'. There is a 'remove' button next to them, however I wish to become more comfortable in the CLI.
I am familiar with the `apt-get remove {package}` command, but don't know the exact name of the package I want removed...
How can I find a specific app's name via the terminal?

This is what I've got so far:

```
dpkg -l | less
/mines
/Mines
```

However, I don't find any packages containing the search term ('Mines', in this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all the present packages on your system by:

`dpkg-query --list *name*`  Adding any keyword you wish as *name*, wildcards permitted as well

Also depending on which version of Ubuntu you are using, you can write e.g.:

`apt-get remove *name*`  , press double Tab, and you will be shown the packages starting by your *name* introduced.